# LD_LIBRARY_PATH: Cannot open shared object file

Tags: c++, c, linux

I have a problem with environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

When I run my bin, I get this error message:

> ./bignum: error while loading shared libraries: liballjoyn.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I added my library to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, like:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:'/home/nyu-debian/Desktop/Stage-Kaliterre/Project/Projects/AllJoyn/core/alljoyn/build/linux/x86_64/release/dist/cpp/lib/liballjoyn.so'
```

I also tried:

- `put -L` option - not working.
- change `export` by `env` with the ./bignum in the end - not working.

All my attempts didn't work... what else can I try?

I'm on Debian Wheezy. This command work last weekend, but now it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Have a look at man ldconfig

Comment: @alk I don't think that's a good duplicate. It does not tell what is wrong with the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` presented in this question. There probably is a duplicate which covers the problem (of specifying *file* instead of directory), but that's not it.

Comment: The real problem was really stupid...

Error: 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:'<path>/lib/ <====

Soluation:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:'<path>/lib  <====

Sorry for this useless post and thanks for your answers. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is a *path*. Therefore, try this, without the library file name:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:'/home/nyu-debian/Desktop/Stage-Kaliterre/Project/Projects/AllJoyn/core/alljoyn/build/linux/x86_64/release/dist/cpp/lib'
```

Answer (score 7):

Try with this :

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/nyu-debian/Desktop/Stage-Kaliterre/Project/Projects/AllJoyn/core/alljoyn/build/linux/x86_64/release/dist/cpp/lib
```

Without `liballjoyn.so` because LD_LIBRARY_PATH is a path.